# How to install itunes on osx with homebrew?

Tags: macos, itunes, homebrew

I couldn't find any itunes on homebrew to be able to install.
Am I missing something?

I tried:

```
brew search itune
```

I've got

```
Caskroom/cask/itunes-producer       Caskroom/cask/itunesscrobbler
Caskroom/cask/itunes-volume-control
```

Comment: Doesn't your OSX has iTunes pre-installed ?

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use Caskroom/cask/iexplorer that complained that it doesn't find "iTunes Music Library XML" and I assumed that it doesn't find it because I don't have iTunes installed. Now that you said I found it and i shared "ITunes Library XMl with other applications". My windows&linux intuitions still don't work smoothly on OSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t. The only way to install programs like iTunes is with [Homebrew Cask](http://caskroom.io/); but it doesn’t provide iTunes because it’s already pre-installed on OS X and “*Apple pushes iTunes updates automatically as part of system updates, so there’s no reason why anyone should be using homebrew-cask to install this*” (the [quote](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/pull/13267#issuecomment-131250692) comes from a Homebrew-Cask maintainer).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this with the link to github. Nevertheless iTunes is not part of the OS so you might want to pin an older version, uninstall. At least it would be nice for homebrew to acknowledge that there is no need to install it since is managed automatically by OS.

Comment: What makes you say it isn’t part of the OS? You can also delete Notepad on Windows. It’s still part of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not missing anything.

There is no **iTunes** formula aka package available in **Homebrew**
Also iTunes comes pre-installed in OSX

This returns nothing

```
brew search | grep itunes
```

You might want to check [this](https://superuser.com/a/390196/270195) too

Comment: You can use `brew search itunes` instead of `brew search | grep itunes`.

Comment: @bfontaine Idea behind brew search | grep is to list all the packages & then grep itunes.

Comment: yes I understand that, but `brew search itunes` does the same, faster.

Comment: @bfontaine OP has already done that & he was thinking he is missing something. My point in doing it my way was to show him that there is indeed no package called itunes. As you may be aware `brew search` lists  all the available packages